# What is the easiest way to screenshot every angle of a Sketchup object?

Tags: sketchup

I found on Google 3D warehouse the model of a dice ([link](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=d398c21f479b87f0d37d8b9dd9772b9c))

I would like to have a picture of the dice resting on each side. What is the easiest way to do this ? The rotate tool isn't very intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rememver there being a ability to snap to some views, not having SketchUp on this computer I found them [here](http://sketchup.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=96203). If you find the "view" menu, then click on the "Standard Views Drop-Down List" and it will:

> provide you with access to standard
>   views: Top, Bottom, Front, Right,
>   Back, Left, and Isometric. Selecting
>   any of these model views will set your
>   active drawing window to that view.